# Handling http-post (QnetworkAccessManager::post) responses inside QThread

Tags: qt

I'm trying to handle http-post responses in a Qt worker thread. I've tried to do this the general recommended way, i.e. I create a thread as follows:

```
_thread = new QThread;
_worker = new Worker(this);
_worker->moveToThread(_thread);
// start the worker thread
connect(_thread, SIGNAL(started()), _worker, SLOT(process()));
```

And then in function `process` I do the following:

```
do {
    QNetworkAccesManger netw;
    // init req (headers) and payload
    //....
    QNetworkReply *reply = newt.post(req, payload);
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(onReadyRead()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(onFinished()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    QThread::msleep(200);
} while (!terminate);
```

`onReadyRead` and `onFinished` are slots in the worker object. Problem is that `onReadyRead` or `onFinished` are never called. I believe this is because I'm not handling the events in the while loop.

I've tried a similar approach, where instead of using `moveToThread` I directly subclass QThread, in that way everything works as expected. I assume this is because QThread::run calls to exec() in order to handle events.

However I believe subclassing QThread is not the recommended way, can anybody explain what I'm missing here??

Comment: Where are `onReadyRead()` and `onFinished()` declared? Are they slots in the worker object?

Comment: Yes, those are slots in the worker object. I've edited the question with this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe this is because I'm not handling the events in the while
> loop.

You are right, this is because you never handle events in your thread. But, you are wrong that you should be doing this in your `while` loop.

Let's examine what is happening here. Normally, when the `QThread` is started, [`run()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#run) function is called in the new thread which (if it has not been overridden) calls [`exec()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#exec). The `exec()` function provides an event loop for the thread, **this is where the thread should be processing events**.

In your code, [`started()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#started) is emitted (Note that this happens even before the `run()` function is called), this causes `Worker::process()` function to be called. And since your `process()` implementation never returns (unless when the thread is required to terminate), your thread never gets into the event loop to process events (as it is always executing the `do-while` loop in your `process` implementation) and `QNetworkAccessManager` can not tell it about the new signals it has.

#### Conclusion:

You should **never** have a function that never returns in an event-driven system. You should always return from your functions as soon as possible, so that the event loop can process pending events.

If you mean to execute the code in the `do-while` loop every `200` msecs, You should use a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html), connect its [`timeout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#timeout) signal to the slot that should be executed every `200` msecs, then [`start()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#start) it with an interval of `200` msecs.

So, Here is how your code may look like:

```
_thread = new QThread;
_worker = new Worker(this);
_worker->moveToThread(_thread);
// start the worker thread
//calling init instead of process
//init will be responsible to schedule calls to "process" every 200 msecs
connect(_thread, SIGNAL(started()), _worker, SLOT(init()));
```

the `init` function should look something like this:

```
QTimer* timer= new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(process()));
//call "process" slot every 200 msecs
timer->start(200);
//call "process" the first time
process();
```

the `process` slot is much simpler now:

```
QNetworkAccesManger netw;
// init req (headers) and payload
//....
QNetworkReply *reply = newt.post(req, payload);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(onReadyRead()), Qt::DirectConnection);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(onFinished()), Qt::DirectConnection);
```